# How to rotate several parts with respect to origin without changing its (x,y) coordinates in KiCAD?

Tags: kicad

Say I have a part located at coordinates (50,50) and I want to rotate it 10 degrees w.r.t. origin. To do so, I will select the part and press "Move Exactly" and key in these values:

[image]

Now the problem is I have 50 seperate parts that I need to rotate in this manner. Viewing each part's coordinates individually and rotating them manually is very repetitive and I'm sure I'm missing some shortcut. Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:

Before photo: 
[image]

What I'm intending to do [link](http://www.keyboard-layout-editor.com/##@@_r:10&rx:1&y:0.15&x:2&a:7%3B&=%3B&@_y:-0.65&x:1%3B&=&_x:1%3B&=%3B&@_y:-0.78%3B&=%3B&@_y:-0.87&x:4%3B&=%3B&@_y:-0.7&x:2&a:4%3B&=E%3B&@_y:-0.65&x:1%3B&=W&_x:1%3B&=R%3B&@_y:-0.75%3B&=Q%3B&@_y:-0.9&x:4%3B&=T%3B&@_y:-0.7&x:2%3B&=D%3B&@_y:-0.65&x:1%3B&=S&_x:1%3B&=F%3B&@_y:-0.75%3B&=A%3B&@_y:-0.9&x:4%3B&=G%3B&@_y:-0.7&x:2%3B&=C%3B&@_y:-0.65&x:1%3B&=X&_x:1%3B&=V%3B&@_y:-0.9&x:5&a:7%3B&=%3B&@_y:-0.85&a:4%3B&=Z%3B&@_y:-0.9&x:4%3B&=B%3B&@_y:-0.7&x:2%3B&=super%3B&@_y:-0.65&x:1%3B&=Tab&_x:1%3B&=Shift%3B&@_y:-0.9&x:5%3B&=Ctrl%3B&@_y:-0.85%3B&=Esc%3B&@_y:-0.9&x:4%3B&=Bksp%3B&@_r:-10&rx:7&ry:0.965&y:0.045&x:2&a:7%3B&=%3B&@_y:-0.65&x:3%3B&=%3B&@_y:-0.99&x:1%3B&=%3B&@_y:-0.76&x:4%3B&=%3B&@_y:-0.89%3B&=%3B&@_y:-0.71&x:2&a:4%3B&=I%3B&@_y:-0.65&x:1%3B&=U&_x:1%3B&=O%3B&@_y:-0.75&x:4%3B&=P%3B&@_y:-0.89%3B&=Y%3B&@_y:-0.71&x:2%3B&=K%3B&@_y:-0.65&x:1%3B&=J&_x:1%3B&=L%3B&@_y:-0.74&x:4%3B&=%2F:%0A%2F%3B%3B&@_y:-0.9%3B&=H%3B&@_y:-0.71&x:2%3B&=%3C%0A,%3B&@_y:-0.64&x:1%3B&=M&_x:1%3B&=%3E%0A.%3B&@_y:-0.9&x:-1&a:7%3B&=%3B&@_y:-0.85&x:4&a:4%3B&=%3F%0A%2F%2F%3B&@_y:-0.9%3B&=N%3B&@_y:-0.7&x:2%3B&=%2F_%0A-%3B&@_y:-0.65&x:1%3B&=fn&_x:1%3B&=%22%0A'%3B&@_y:-0.9&x:-1%3B&=Alt%3B&@_y:-0.85&x:4%3B&=Enter%3B&@_y:-0.9%3B&=Space):
[image]

Now I am unable to simply rotate it then position it afterwards, as I need the pcb to match with my keyboard switch plate, which is generated from

Comment: Can you show a before/after image of what you are looking for?  Is it individual footprint rotation or group rotation?

Comment: Group rotation for a keyboard. Let me get some photos out

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rotating a group requires selecting the group first.  Note here I am selecting right-to-left which selects everything that touches the selection box.

[image: Select Group]

Then apply the rotation

[image: Rotate]

Result:
[image: Resulting rotation]

---

*Edit*

To answer your comment, let's say that your reference footprint is at 50,50 in x,y and you would like to rotate your group of footprints 10° about the grid origin, keeping the footprints aligned with the radial.

To do this, start with the same procedure as before and select the group you wish to move.

[image: Select Group]

Next, use the same move command as before but this time enter the coordinates of the top left pad in your selection into the x/y boxes

[image: First Step]

Next, change the coordinates type to "Polar".  This will change the values from 50/50 to their equivalent r/theta values.  Now, since you are rotating the group by 10°, you need to adjust the radial position by -10°.  I have also selected "Override default footprint anchor" otherwise, the default anchor will be the center of the group.

[image: Polar]

Comment: However you rotated around the current position. What if I wanted to rotate around the grid origin instead?

Comment: You set the grid origin and that radio button will become enabled.  I did not set a grid origin in my example board, so it was grey

Comment: However the default value of “Move vector x” and “Move vector y” is set to “0” which shifts the parts to the origin, which is not what I want.

Comment: @WetFeet - I've updated the answer to include a section for rotating about the origin at arbitrary offset